# Creating a new dataframe with filtered rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, jupyter

Using jupyternotebook, I am trying to create a new dataframe (`data`) from a dataframe (`df`), which excludes rows where `ICU = 1` or `WINDOW = "ABOVE_12"`.

Each exclusion works separately:

```py
data = df[df["WINDOW"] != "ABOVE_12"]
data = df[(df["ICU"] != 1)]
```

When I try them together, only the ICU rows are filtered.

```py
data = df[(df['ICU'] != 1) | (df['WINDOW'] != "ABOVE_12")]
```

I need to exclude any row that contains *either* condition, not rows that meet *both* conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use AND (`&`) not OR (`|`) in your condition, following [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
data = df[(df['ICU'] != 1) & (df['WINDOW'] != "ABOVE_12")]
```

Alternatively:

```
data = df[~((df['ICU'] == 1) | (df['WINDOW'] == "ABOVE_12"))]
```

Truth(-like) table:

```
         WINDOW == "ABOVE_12"   WINDOW != "ABOVE_12"
ICU == 1                 drop                   drop
ICU != 1                 drop                   keep <- intersection is AND
```